# Content Assist not showing in editor setting of eclipe IDE Mars V 4.5.1

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

I'm using Eclipse Mars v 4.5.1 I don't see **"Content Assist"** in Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor

what seems to the problem ??

Comment: Can you confirm, you do have Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor, just not the Content Assist under it? The two preference pages are provided by the same plug-in (org.eclipse.jdt.ui). Also, do you have other pages under Editor, i.e. is it just Content Assist missing?

Comment: I found Content Assist under Edit Menu but there is no option like "Auto activation triggers for Java" and it's still missing in Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor and as far as I could investigate Content Assist is missing but not sure if any other part is missing or only this one

Comment: an other problem I just found I can't comment I press ctrl+shift+L to see all available shortcuts and there is nothing for comment there as if IDE doesn't have it at all

Comment: I also tried Luna Release V4.4.0 but it was same as Mars V4.5.1

Comment: That all sounds rather strange that you have some (much?) of Eclipse working. Do you have any errors in your workspace log (workspace/.metadata/.log) that may indicate the problem? Are you running with a Java 8 JVM or earlier? What platform are you using?